# On 'ISession.Refresh' NHibernate generates two instances for the the same database record on the Session Cache. Why and how to solve it?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

On `ISession.Refresh` NHibernate generates two instances for the the same database record on the Session Cache.

**WHY?**

The problem seems to be related to 'Composite Id' using 'KeyReference' ('key-many-to-one'). The situation occurs in versions '2.1.2.4000' and '3.2.0.4000' of NHibernate.

**How can I solve this problem without giving up "composite id"?**

The following test should pass but it does not:

```
/// <summary>
/// Test for <see cref="ISession.Refresh(object)"/>. After a call to 
/// <c>Refresh()</c>On 'ISession.Refresh' NHibernate GENERATES two 
/// instances for the the same database record on the Session Cache. WHY?.
/// The problem seems to be related to 'Composit Id' using 'KeyReference'.
/// ('key-many-to-one'). The situation occurs in versions '2.1.2.4000' and 
/// '3.2.0.4000' of NHibernate. This test should pass, but does not pass!
/// <para>There is another test (<see cref="SofPOC.Questions.NHRefresh.NHRefreshTest"/>) 
/// that makes the 'Refresh' in several scenarios where this problem does 
/// not occur.
/// </para>
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// Tables:
/// <code>
/// MasterCategory:
/// Id|Description
/// --+-----------
/// 1 |Cat_1      
/// 2 |Cat_2      
/// 
/// Master:
/// IdA|IdB|Description  |MasterCategoryId
/// ---+---+-------------+----------------
/// 1  |1  |MASTER_DESC_1|1               
/// 2  |2  |MASTER_DESC_2|2               
/// 
/// Detail:
/// MasterIdA|MasterIdB|SubId|Description    
/// ---------+---------+-----+---------------
/// 1        |1        |1    |DETAIL_DESC_1_1
/// 1        |1        |2    |DETAIL_DESC_1_2
/// 1        |1        |3    |DETAIL_DESC_1_3
/// 2        |2        |4    |DETAIL_DESC_2_1
/// 2        |2        |5    |DETAIL_DESC_2_2        
/// </code>
/// </remarks>
[TestFixture]
public class NHRefreshCpIdTest
{
    private static readonly ILog LOG = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(NHRefreshCpIdTest));

    public ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; set; }

    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void TestFixtureSetUp()
    {
        File.Copy("./Questions/NHRefreshCpId/NHRefreshCpIdTest.db", "./Questions/NHRefreshCpId/NHRefreshCpIdTestEdited.db", true);

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionProvider] = "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider";
        config.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionDriver] = "NHibernate.Driver.SQLite20Driver";
        config.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ConnectionString] = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|./Questions/NHRefreshCpId/NHRefreshCpIdTestEdited.db;Version=3;FailIfMissing=True;";
        config.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.Dialect] = "NHibernate.Dialect.SQLiteDialect";
        //config.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.By]
        config.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ShowSql] = "true";
        config.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.FormatSql] = "true";
        FluentConfiguration fConfigure = Fluently.Configure(config);
#if NH2
        config.Properties[NHibernate.Cfg.Environment.ProxyFactoryFactoryClass] = "NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle";
#endif
        fConfigure.Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(MasterCategoryEntMap)));
        fConfigure.Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(MasterEntMap)));
        fConfigure.Mappings(m =>
            m.FluentMappings.Add(typeof(DetailEntMap)));
        config = fConfigure.BuildConfiguration();

        this.SessionFactory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        ISession ss = null;


        #region teste
        ss = this.SessionFactory.OpenSession();
        try
        {
            MasterEnt master1BeforeRefresh = ss.Get<MasterEnt>(new MasterCpId(1, 1));
            MasterEnt master2BeforeRefresh = ss.Get<MasterEnt>(new MasterCpId(2, 2));
            MasterCategoryEnt masterCat1BeforeRefresh = master1BeforeRefresh.MasterCategory;
            MasterCategoryEnt masterCat2BeforeRefresh = ss.Get<MasterCategoryEnt>(2);

            #region persist data using NHibernate
            ITransaction tx = ss.BeginTransaction();
            ss.Flush();
            tx.Commit();
            #endregion

            #region change data out of NHibernate
            IDbCommand command = ss.Connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE Master SET MasterCategoryId = 2 WHERE IdA = 1 and IdB = 1";
            IDbTransaction dbTx = ss.Connection.BeginTransaction();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dbTx.Commit();
            #endregion

            LOG.Debug("JUST BEFORE 'Refresh'");

            ss.Refresh(master1BeforeRefresh);
            MasterEnt master1AfterRefresh = ss.Get<MasterEnt>(new MasterCpId(1, 1));
            DetailEnt detail4AfterRefresh = ss.Get<DetailEnt>(new DetailCpId(master1AfterRefresh, 4));
            MasterCategoryEnt masterCat1AfterRefresh = ss.Get<MasterCategoryEnt>(1);
            MasterCategoryEnt masterCat2AfterRefresh = master1AfterRefresh.MasterCategory;

            //Here is the test
            Assert.AreEqual(1, masterCat1BeforeRefresh.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(1, masterCat1AfterRefresh.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, masterCat2BeforeRefresh.Id);
            Assert.AreEqual(2, masterCat2AfterRefresh.Id);
            Assert.AreSame(master1BeforeRefresh, master1AfterRefresh);
            Assert.AreSame(masterCat1BeforeRefresh, masterCat1AfterRefresh);
            Assert.AreSame(masterCat2BeforeRefresh, masterCat2AfterRefresh);
        }
        finally
        {
            ss.Close();
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

I'm using:

- NHibernate 2.1.2
- NHibernate 3.2.0
- System.Data.SQLite 1.0.80.0

The complete source is here: [NHibernateRefresh.7z](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/49510149/stackoverflow/dotnet/NHibernateRefresh.7z)

**NOTES:**

- Before opening the solution (".\ Src\SofPOC.2010.sln") run ".\Dependencies\setup.bat" to load dependencies.
- See ".\readme.txt" and ".\dependencies\readme.txt" for instructions about the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause:**

On a call to 'DefaultRefreshEventListener.OnRefresh' for 'Parent', 
ocurre a 'Load with join' between 'Parent' and 'Child', 
the 'Child' is loaded first and, after that, the 'Parent', but at this 
moment the 'Parent' was temporarily removed from the session, then, 
'Child' refers the 'Parent' by a proxy. 
Although 'parent1BeforeRefresh' and 'parent1AfterRefresh' are 
different instances, 'parent1AfterRefresh' is a proxy that points to 
'parent1BeforeRefresh'. The problem is more severe in 
'child1BeforeRefresh' and 'child1AfterRefresh' because these instances 
are totally unrelated and both are in the session cache.

**The solution** [(NH-3253)](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3253)**:**

If [NH-3253](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3253) has not yet been accepted and fixed, replace the `DefaultRefreshEventListener` by your own:

version 2.1.x:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Defines the default refresh event listener used by hibernate for refreshing entities
/// in response to generated refresh events. 
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class DefaultRefreshEventListener : IRefreshEventListener
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(DefaultRefreshEventListener));

    public virtual void OnRefresh(RefreshEvent @event)
    {
        OnRefresh(@event, IdentityMap.Instantiate(10));
    }

    public virtual void OnRefresh(RefreshEvent @event, IDictionary refreshedAlready)
    {
        IEventSource source = @event.Session;

        if (source.PersistenceContext.ReassociateIfUninitializedProxy(@event.Entity))
            return;

        object obj = source.PersistenceContext.UnproxyAndReassociate(@event.Entity);

        if (refreshedAlready.Contains(obj))
        {
            log.Debug("already refreshed");
            return;
        }

        EntityEntry e = source.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(obj);
        IEntityPersister persister;
        object id;

        if (e == null)
        {
            persister = source.GetEntityPersister(null, obj); //refresh() does not pass an entityName
            id = persister.GetIdentifier(obj, source.EntityMode);
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.Debug("refreshing transient " + MessageHelper.InfoString(persister, id, source.Factory));
            }
            EntityKey key = new EntityKey(id, persister, source.EntityMode);
            if (source.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(key) != null)
            {
                throw new PersistentObjectException("attempted to refresh transient instance when persistent instance was already associated with the Session: " + 
                    MessageHelper.InfoString(persister, id, source.Factory));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.Debug("refreshing " + MessageHelper.InfoString(e.Persister, e.Id, source.Factory));
            }
            if (!e.ExistsInDatabase)
            {
                throw new HibernateException("this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database");
            }

            persister = e.Persister;
            id = e.Id;
        }

        // cascade the refresh prior to refreshing this entity
        refreshedAlready[obj] = obj;
        new Cascade(CascadingAction.Refresh, CascadePoint.BeforeRefresh, source).CascadeOn(persister, obj, refreshedAlready);

        if (e != null)
        {
            EntityKey key = new EntityKey(id, persister, source.EntityMode);
            source.PersistenceContext.RemoveEntity(key);
            if (persister.HasCollections)
                new EvictVisitor(source).Process(obj, persister);
        }

        if (persister.HasCache)
        {
            CacheKey ck = new CacheKey(id, persister.IdentifierType, persister.RootEntityName, source.EntityMode, source.Factory);
            persister.Cache.Remove(ck);
        }

        EvictCachedCollections(persister, id, source.Factory);

        // NH Different behavior : NH-1601
        // At this point the entity need the real refresh, all elementes of collections are Refreshed,
        // the collection state was evicted, but the PersistentCollection (in the entity state)
        // is associated with a possible previous session.
        new WrapVisitor(source).Process(obj, persister);

        // NH-3253: Forcing simple load to prevent the redundante instance 
        //on session:
        //Ocurre when:
        // -there is a 'one-to-many' 'Parent-Child' relationship;
        // -AND the 'Parent' 'many-to-one' association is ' fetch="select" ';
        // -AND 'Child' is using a 'composite-id' and 'key-many-to-one' to the
        //'Parent'.
        object result;
        if (this.IsReferencedByCompositeId(persister))
            result = persister.Load(id, obj, @event.LockMode, source);

        string previousFetchProfile = source.FetchProfile;
        source.FetchProfile = "refresh";
        result = persister.Load(id, obj, @event.LockMode, source);
        source.FetchProfile = previousFetchProfile;

        // NH Different behavior : we are ignoring transient entities without throw any kind of exception 
        // because a transient entity is "self refreshed"
        if (!ForeignKeys.IsTransient(persister.EntityName, obj, result == null, @event.Session))
            UnresolvableObjectException.ThrowIfNull(result, id, persister.EntityName);
    }

    private Dictionary<EntityMetamodel, bool> IsReferencedByCompositeIdCache = new Dictionary<EntityMetamodel, bool>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns <c>true</c> if the entity in <paramref name="persister"/> 
    /// ('root') has a direct or indirect association with another 
    /// entity that is associated back to 'root' through a 'composit-id' and 
    /// 'key-many-to-one'.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="persister"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool IsReferencedByCompositeId(IEntityPersister persister)
    {
        try
        {
            bool result = false;
            if (IsReferencedByCompositeIdCache.ContainsKey(persister.EntityMetamodel))
            {
                result = this.IsReferencedByCompositeIdCache[persister.EntityMetamodel];
            }
            else
            {
                EntityMetamodel em =
                    this.GetReferrerByCompositeId(
                        persister.EntityMetamodel,
                        persister.EntityMetamodel,
                        false,
                        new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<EntityMetamodel>());
                if (em == null)
                    result = false;
                else
                    result = true;

                lock (this)
                {
                    this.IsReferencedByCompositeIdCache[persister.EntityMetamodel] = result;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Unespected ERROR!", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursive Helper for <see cref="IsReferencedByCompositeId(IEntityPersister)"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootEM"></param>
    /// <param name="nestedEM"></param>
    /// <param name="neestedIsCompositeId"></param>
    /// <param name="visitedList"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private EntityMetamodel GetReferrerByCompositeId(
        EntityMetamodel rootEM,
        EntityMetamodel nestedEM,
        bool neestedIsCompositeId,
        ICollection<EntityMetamodel> visitedList)
    {
        EntityMetamodel emResult = null;

        if (visitedList.Contains(nestedEM))
        {
            return emResult;
        }
        else
        {
            visitedList.Add(nestedEM);

            ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionImplementor = rootEM.SessionFactory;

            if (nestedEM.IdentifierProperty.Type is IAbstractComponentType)
            {
                IAbstractComponentType componentType = (IAbstractComponentType)nestedEM.IdentifierProperty.Type;
                for (int i = 0; i < componentType.Subtypes.Length; i++)
                {
                    IType subType = componentType.Subtypes[i];
                    if (!subType.IsAnyType
                        && subType.IsAssociationType
                        && subType is IAssociationType)
                    {
                        IAssociationType associationType = (IAssociationType)subType;
                        string associatedEntityName = null;
                        try
                        {
                            //for 'Collection Types', sometimes 'Element Type' is not an 'Entity Type'
                            associatedEntityName = associationType.GetAssociatedEntityName(sessionImplementor);
                        }
                        catch (MappingException me)
                        {
                            //I think it will never happen because a 
                            //"Composit Id" can not have a property that 
                            //uses 'NHibernate.Type.CollectionType'. 
                            //But just in case ...
                            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
                                log.Debug("Can not perform 'GetAssociatedEntityName'. " +
                                    "Considering it is not an entity type: '" +
                                    nestedEM.IdentifierProperty.Name + "." +
                                    componentType.PropertyNames[i] + "'"
                                    , me);
                        }
                        if (associatedEntityName != null)
                        {
                            IEntityPersister persisterNextNested = sessionImplementor.GetEntityPersister(associatedEntityName);
                            if (rootEM == persisterNextNested.EntityMetamodel)
                            {
                                emResult = nestedEM;
                                return emResult;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                emResult = this.GetReferrerByCompositeId(
                                    rootEM,
                                    persisterNextNested.EntityMetamodel,
                                    true,
                                    visitedList);

                                if (emResult != null)
                                    return emResult;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nestedEM.Properties.Length; i++)
            {
                StandardProperty property = nestedEM.Properties[i];

                if (!property.Type.IsAnyType
                    && property.Type.IsAssociationType
                    && property.Type is IAssociationType)
                {
                    IAssociationType associationType = (IAssociationType)property.Type;
                    string associatedEntityName = null;
                    try
                    {
                        //for 'Collection Types', sometimes 'Element Type' is not an 'Entity Type'
                        associatedEntityName = associationType.GetAssociatedEntityName(sessionImplementor);
                    }
                    catch (MappingException me)
                    {
                        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
                            log.Debug("Can not perform 'GetAssociatedEntityName'. " +
                                    "Considering it is not an entity type: '" +
                                    nestedEM.EntityType.Name + "." +
                                    nestedEM.PropertyNames[i] + "'",
                                me);
                    }
                    if (associatedEntityName != null)
                    {
                        IEntityPersister persisterNextNested = sessionImplementor.GetEntityPersister(associatedEntityName);
                        emResult = this.GetReferrerByCompositeId(
                            rootEM,
                            persisterNextNested.EntityMetamodel,
                            false,
                            visitedList);
                        if (emResult != null)
                            return emResult;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Evict collections from the factory-level cache
    private void EvictCachedCollections(IEntityPersister persister, object id, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    {
        EvictCachedCollections(persister.PropertyTypes, id, factory);
    }

    private void EvictCachedCollections(IType[] types, object id, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
        {
            if (types[i].IsCollectionType)
            {
                factory.EvictCollection(((CollectionType)types[i]).Role, id);
            }
            else if (types[i].IsComponentType)
            {
                IAbstractComponentType actype = (IAbstractComponentType)types[i];
                EvictCachedCollections(actype.Subtypes, id, factory);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

version 3.3.x:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Defines the default refresh event listener used by hibernate for refreshing entities
/// in response to generated refresh events. 
/// </summary>
[Serializable]
public class DefaultRefreshEventListener : IRefreshEventListener
{
    private static readonly IInternalLogger log = LoggerProvider.LoggerFor(typeof(DefaultRefreshEventListener));

    public virtual void OnRefresh(RefreshEvent @event)
    {
        OnRefresh(@event, IdentityMap.Instantiate(10));
    }

    public virtual void OnRefresh(RefreshEvent @event, IDictionary refreshedAlready)
    {
        IEventSource source = @event.Session;

        bool isTransient = !source.Contains(@event.Entity);
        if (source.PersistenceContext.ReassociateIfUninitializedProxy(@event.Entity))
        {
            if (isTransient)
                source.SetReadOnly(@event.Entity, source.DefaultReadOnly);
            return;
        }

        object obj = source.PersistenceContext.UnproxyAndReassociate(@event.Entity);

        if (refreshedAlready.Contains(obj))
        {
            log.Debug("already refreshed");
            return;
        }

        EntityEntry e = source.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(obj);
        IEntityPersister persister;
        object id;

        if (e == null)
        {
            persister = source.GetEntityPersister(null, obj); //refresh() does not pass an entityName
            id = persister.GetIdentifier(obj, source.EntityMode);
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.Debug("refreshing transient " + MessageHelper.InfoString(persister, id, source.Factory));
            }
            EntityKey key = new EntityKey(id, persister, source.EntityMode);
            if (source.PersistenceContext.GetEntry(key) != null)
            {
                throw new PersistentObjectException("attempted to refresh transient instance when persistent instance was already associated with the Session: " + 
                    MessageHelper.InfoString(persister, id, source.Factory));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                log.Debug("refreshing " + MessageHelper.InfoString(e.Persister, e.Id, source.Factory));
            }
            if (!e.ExistsInDatabase)
            {
                throw new HibernateException("this instance does not yet exist as a row in the database");
            }

            persister = e.Persister;
            id = e.Id;
        }

        // cascade the refresh prior to refreshing this entity
        refreshedAlready[obj] = obj;
        new Cascade(CascadingAction.Refresh, CascadePoint.BeforeRefresh, source).CascadeOn(persister, obj, refreshedAlready);

        if (e != null)
        {
            EntityKey key = new EntityKey(id, persister, source.EntityMode);
            source.PersistenceContext.RemoveEntity(key);
            if (persister.HasCollections)
                new EvictVisitor(source).Process(obj, persister);
        }

        if (persister.HasCache)
        {
            CacheKey ck = new CacheKey(id, persister.IdentifierType, persister.RootEntityName, source.EntityMode, source.Factory);
            persister.Cache.Remove(ck);
        }

        EvictCachedCollections(persister, id, source.Factory);

        // NH Different behavior : NH-1601
        // At this point the entity need the real refresh, all elementes of collections are Refreshed,
        // the collection state was evicted, but the PersistentCollection (in the entity state)
        // is associated with a possible previous session.
        new WrapVisitor(source).Process(obj, persister);

        // NH-3253: Forcing simple load to prevent the redundante instance 
        //on session:
        //Ocurre when:
        // -there is a 'one-to-many' 'Parent-Child' relationship;
        // -AND the 'Parent' 'many-to-one' association is ' fetch="select" ';
        // -AND 'Child' is using a 'composite-id' and 'key-many-to-one' to the
        //'Parent'.
        object result;
        if (this.IsReferencedByCompositeId(persister))
            result = persister.Load(id, obj, @event.LockMode, source);

        string previousFetchProfile = source.FetchProfile;
        source.FetchProfile = "refresh";
        result = persister.Load(id, obj, @event.LockMode, source);

        if (result != null)
            if (!persister.IsMutable)
                source.SetReadOnly(result, true);
            else
                source.SetReadOnly(result, (e == null ? source.DefaultReadOnly : e.IsReadOnly));

        source.FetchProfile = previousFetchProfile;

        // NH Different behavior : we are ignoring transient entities without throw any kind of exception
        // because a transient entity is "self refreshed"
        if (!ForeignKeys.IsTransient(persister.EntityName, obj, result == null, @event.Session))
            UnresolvableObjectException.ThrowIfNull(result, id, persister.EntityName);
    }

    private Dictionary<EntityMetamodel, bool> IsReferencedByCompositeIdCache = new Dictionary<EntityMetamodel, bool>();
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns <c>true</c> if the entity in <paramref name="persister"/> 
    /// ('root') has a direct or indirect association with another 
    /// entity that is associated back to 'root' through a 'composit-id' and 
    /// 'key-many-to-one'.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="persister"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool IsReferencedByCompositeId(IEntityPersister persister)
    {
        try
        {
            bool result = false;
            if (IsReferencedByCompositeIdCache.ContainsKey(persister.EntityMetamodel))
            {
                result = this.IsReferencedByCompositeIdCache[persister.EntityMetamodel];
            }
            else
            {
                EntityMetamodel em =
                    this.GetReferrerByCompositeId(
                        persister.EntityMetamodel,
                        persister.EntityMetamodel,
                        false,
                        new Iesi.Collections.Generic.HashedSet<EntityMetamodel>());
                if (em == null)
                    result = false;
                else
                    result = true;

                lock (this)
                {
                    this.IsReferencedByCompositeIdCache[persister.EntityMetamodel] = result;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("Unespected ERROR!", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Recursive Helper for <see cref="IsReferencedByCompositeId(IEntityPersister)"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="rootEM"></param>
    /// <param name="nestedEM"></param>
    /// <param name="neestedIsCompositeId"></param>
    /// <param name="visitedList"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private EntityMetamodel GetReferrerByCompositeId(
        EntityMetamodel rootEM,
        EntityMetamodel nestedEM,
        bool neestedIsCompositeId,
        ICollection<EntityMetamodel> visitedList)
    {
        EntityMetamodel emResult = null;

        if (visitedList.Contains(nestedEM))
        {
            return emResult;
        }
        else
        {
            visitedList.Add(nestedEM);

            ISessionFactoryImplementor sessionImplementor = rootEM.SessionFactory;

            if (nestedEM.IdentifierProperty.Type is IAbstractComponentType)
            {
                IAbstractComponentType componentType = (IAbstractComponentType)nestedEM.IdentifierProperty.Type;
                for (int i = 0; i < componentType.Subtypes.Length; i++)
                {
                    IType subType = componentType.Subtypes[i];
                    if (!subType.IsAnyType
                        && subType.IsAssociationType
                        && subType is IAssociationType)
                    {
                        IAssociationType associationType = (IAssociationType)subType;
                        string associatedEntityName = null;
                        try
                        {
                            //for 'Collection Types', sometimes 'Element Type' is not an 'Entity Type'
                            associatedEntityName = associationType.GetAssociatedEntityName(sessionImplementor);
                        }
                        catch (MappingException me)
                        {
                            //I think it will never happen because a 
                            //"Composit Id" can not have a property that 
                            //uses 'NHibernate.Type.CollectionType'. 
                            //But just in case ...
                            if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
                                log.Debug("Can not perform 'GetAssociatedEntityName'. " +
                                    "Considering it is not an entity type: '" +
                                    nestedEM.IdentifierProperty.Name + "." +
                                    componentType.PropertyNames[i] + "'"
                                    , me);
                        }
                        if (associatedEntityName != null)
                        {
                            IEntityPersister persisterNextNested = sessionImplementor.GetEntityPersister(associatedEntityName);
                            if (rootEM == persisterNextNested.EntityMetamodel)
                            {
                                emResult = nestedEM;
                                return emResult;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                emResult = this.GetReferrerByCompositeId(
                                    rootEM,
                                    persisterNextNested.EntityMetamodel,
                                    true,
                                    visitedList);

                                if (emResult != null)
                                    return emResult;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < nestedEM.Properties.Length; i++)
            {
                StandardProperty property = nestedEM.Properties[i];

                if (!property.Type.IsAnyType
                    && property.Type.IsAssociationType
                    && property.Type is IAssociationType)
                {
                    IAssociationType associationType = (IAssociationType)property.Type;
                    string associatedEntityName = null;
                    try
                    {
                        //for 'Collection Types', sometimes 'Element Type' is not an 'Entity Type'
                        associatedEntityName = associationType.GetAssociatedEntityName(sessionImplementor);
                    }
                    catch (MappingException me)
                    {
                        if (log.IsDebugEnabled)
                            log.Debug("Can not perform 'GetAssociatedEntityName'. " +
                                    "Considering it is not an entity type: '" +
                                    nestedEM.EntityType.Name + "." +
                                    nestedEM.PropertyNames[i] + "'",
                                me);
                    }
                    if (associatedEntityName != null)
                    {
                        IEntityPersister persisterNextNested = sessionImplementor.GetEntityPersister(associatedEntityName);
                        emResult = this.GetReferrerByCompositeId(
                            rootEM,
                            persisterNextNested.EntityMetamodel,
                            false,
                            visitedList);
                        if (emResult != null)
                            return emResult;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    // Evict collections from the factory-level cache
    private void EvictCachedCollections(IEntityPersister persister, object id, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    {
        EvictCachedCollections(persister.PropertyTypes, id, factory);
    }

    private void EvictCachedCollections(IType[] types, object id, ISessionFactoryImplementor factory)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
        {
            if (types[i].IsCollectionType)
            {
                factory.EvictCollection(((CollectionType)types[i]).Role, id);
            }
            else if (types[i].IsComponentType)
            {
                IAbstractComponentType actype = (IAbstractComponentType)types[i];
                EvictCachedCollections(actype.Subtypes, id, factory);
            }
        }
    }
}
```